# Can't see my Nexus 4 with fastboot on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, android, devices

I have just received my Nexus 4 and I want to plug it in to root it/copy files onto it but somehow I can't see it while I use

`$sudo fastboot devices`

I am using this version of fastboot on my ubuntu laptop

`android-tools-fastboot     4.1.1+git20120801-1`

**EDIT**

While the issue of rooting the device was solved (simply fastboot only sees devices while they are in bootloader) I still cannot see the device while I plug it in the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update your gvfs file to enable your computer to see Nexus 4 files. Use the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After you update, reboot your computer. When you connect the Nexus 4 to the PC, make sure its unlocked. This should help you. :)

If you are trying to use adb and cannot see your device, change the ownership of your ~/.android folder to the current user .

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.android
```

For more details see [here](http://www.tuxtrix.com/2013/03/how-to-fix-android-devices-not.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus 4 does not have a mass storage mode. I recommend using [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) instead, as it will allow you to upload/download/manage files on your Nexus device remotely.

Comment: His question was a bit unlcear, he wanted to have developer access via fastboot or adb, AirDroid dosen't provide that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I have had "fast USB charge" option checked in kernel that I have installed http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2002782

After unchecking that I can see folders on my Nexus 4.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link out. It worked for me.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2004182

Answer (score 0):

Per [Nexus 4 not detected as USB device with OTA update 4.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336317/nexus-4-not-detected-as-usb-device-with-ota-update-4-3)

`Settings → Storage → ⋮ → USB-connection to computer → MTP media device ☑`