# Unable to connect Nexus 4 with 12.10

Tags: 12.10, mount, android, mtp, nexus-4

Yesterday, when I'd connected my Nexus 4 on my laptop it still managed to read it and gave me the option for MTP or PTP. My laptop was able to detect the phone in PTP mode but not MTP.

Today, when I connected my phone again the option for MTP or PTP doesn't show up on my notification area anymore.

I tried following the instructions from the [XDA Developers post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2004182) but I could not continue after step #6.

[image: xdascreenshot].

I also tried updating my gvfs file from this [Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264008/cant-see-my-nexus-4-with-fastboot-on-ubuntu-12-10) but still no PTP/MTP option popped from my notification area.

I also always take note to unlock my phone when I connect it on my laptop but it makes no difference.

Help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it on 12.xx - as of 13.04 this is part of core.

http://www.gaggl.com/2013/03/connection-android-4-x-mtp-mass-storage-to-ubuntu-12-x/

HTH

Comment: Did not work for me in 12.04