# Nexus 4 not detected as USB device with OTA update 4.3

Tags: usb, android, mtp, nexus-4

I have submitted [a question on the Google Mobile forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mobile/nexus%24204%2420usb/mobile/k7nc9BHbmzY/Hr9hVsuGZQEJ), but not had any responses yet.

I am fairly certain that my issues with USB connectivity started when I allowed the 4.3 OTA update to install on my personal handset. I have developed apps for it, used it for testing, and have mounted it via USB without issue (mtptools, etc) previously. Now I can't even find my device on lsusb; compared to a test device at work (another Nexus 4, which is still at 4.2.2) my phone effectively is dead to any machine apart for being a device to charge.

My phone is standard-issue Android Nexus 4 and I want to avoid going down 'root road'; are there any suggestions in finding out the cause/possible fixes? Even a Windows machine can detect the 4.2.2 Nexus 4 as a media device, but not my 'upgraded' one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just discovered this issue on my Nexus 4 this afternoon. Good to know at least someone else is running into this issue. I find it odd that not even lsusb sees it...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but I solved it a few seconds ago after reading a post on another forum.
It seems like the MTP option somehow got unchecked (not by me!), maybe when installing the latest Android update…

> Settings → Storage → ⋮ → USB-connection to computer → MTP media device ☑

Note that I run Android in Swedish, so the line above is only a translation from Swedish to English…

Comment: This worked for me too except I had to choose PTP (Camera device) because of a group policy (WinXP) preventing MTP.

Comment: Not working with Nexus 7.. i can't my deivce in mac as MTP

Answer (score 0):

1. Plug in your phone
2. Go to Device Manager
3. Look for Acer Device
4. Expand that and you will see something like ACER Composite ADB Interface
5. Right click and delete that
6. Unplug and replug your phone and you should be able to get it.

Here's another tutorial if the method above doesn't work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0MGt_0_jCQ